# How to solve a Dataset problem in python?

Tags: python

i have a dataset with different programming language in a column titled and i want to get the 10 most used programming language in my dataset python

Dataset:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nJLDFSdIbkNxcqY7NBtJZfcgLW1wpsUZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you asking how to (using python) find the 10 most used programming languages depicted in this dataset?

Comment: how about something like `df["Your main technology / programming language"].value_counts()[:10]` ?

Comment: for column `Other technologies/programming languages you use often` you would have to `split` text on `,` and `extract` to separated rows.

Answer (score 0):

On StackOverflow, you should not link to outside sources, but include relevant data in your question.  You should also pare down the data - if it is long, make it as short as possible and still illustrate your question.

Finally, on StackOverflow, we don't ask bare questions like "how to do x".  You must first make an effort yourself to solve your problem, and then, if you don't understand why your code does not work, then you post the smallest possible example, and we will tell you where the bug is.  You must show the effort first and then we help you fix it.  The purpose of it is so that you learn to code yourself, and not just copy a ready solution.

Since you did not show any effort, I will not give you a complete solution, but I will give you some start to point you in the right direction.  You should first analyze my code so that you understand how it works and then you can finish it.

When you run this code, it will print for you the relevant words.  You should probably further process them, to remove irrelevant characters that people put in, and also to use proper case of letters, and then you can count the occurrences of words.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

LANGUAGE_COLUMN_INDEX = 8

with open('Salary.csv') as fp:

    #skip over first line
    fp.readline()

    for line in fp:
        for word in line.split(',')[LANGUAGE_COLUMN_INDEX].split('/'):
            print(word.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pandas` and you have single elements in column then you can use `.value_counts()` with `[:10]`

Example for column `"Your main technology / programming language"`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('IT Salary Survey EU 2020.csv')

result = df["Your main technology / programming language"].value_counts()[:10]

print(result)
```

Result:

```
Java          184
Python        164
PHP            56
C++            38
JavaScript     34
Javascript     31
C#             30
python         26
Scala          24
Swift          24
Name: Your main technology / programming language, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT:** It seems it needs to convert all text to lower to count together `Python` and `python`

---

If you have many elements separted by `,` in every text then you need to split test (to create list), use `explode()` to move elements from list to separated rows, and later count elements using the same `.value_counts()` with `[:10]`

Example for column `"Other technologies/programming languages you use often"`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('IT Salary Survey EU 2020.csv')

data = df["Other technologies/programming languages you use often"]
data = data.str.split(',')  # convert strings into list of values
data = data.explode()       # convert list into separated rows
data = data.str.strip()     # remove spaces
data = data.str.lower()     # convert all to lower (to count together `Python` and `python`)
result = data.value_counts()[:10]

print(result)
```

Result:

```
docker                     525
sql                        480
python                     409
aws                        401
javascript / typescript    381
kubernetes                 296
java / scala               229
google cloud               150
kotlin                     120
go                         113
Name: Other technologies/programming languages you use often, dtype: int64
```

---

You can also write all in one line

```
result = df["Other technologies/programming languages you use often"].str.split(',').explode().str.strip().str.lower().value_counts()[:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Pandas, here a pure Python version as the Counter imported from the collections module is part of standard Python distribution. The third value in the output gives relative % of entries for given language in relation to the total number of entries (rounded to an integer value):

```
prgrLang = [] # will collect the entries in the table
with open("IT_Salary_Survey_EU_2020.csv") as f:
    Lines = f.readlines()
    for line in Lines[1:]: # [1:] skips the header line
        prgrLang.append(line.split(',')[8]) # column 9 in CSV
noOfEntries = len(Lines)-1
from collections import Counter
objCounter = Counter(prgrLang) # counts same values in a list
lstResults = sorted( [ [value, key] 
                for key, value in objCounter.items() ], reverse=True )
lstResPerc = [ [key, value, int(100*value/noOfEntries)] 
            for value, key in lstResults ] 
print( *lstResPerc, sep='\n' )
```

The code above gives following output:

```
['Java', 182, 14]
['Python', 163, 13]
['', 121, 9]
['PHP', 55, 4]
['C++', 38, 3]
['JavaScript', 34, 2]
['Javascript', 31, 2]
['C#', 29, 2]
['python', 26, 2]
['Swift', 23, 1]
['Scala', 23, 1]
['Go', 23, 1]
['Python ', 21, 1]
['Kotlin', 21, 1]
['Ruby', 19, 1]
['TypeScript', 14, 1]
['SQL', 14, 1]
['.NET', 13, 1]
['Middle', 12, 0]
['JS', 11, 0]
['C', 10, 0]
['iOS', 9, 0]
['R', 9, 0]
['php', 8, 0]
['java', 8, 0]
['Typescript', 8, 0]
['Android', 8, 0]
['javascript', 7, 0]
['Kubernetes', 7, 0]
['.net', 7, 0]
['"Python', 7, 0]
['"Java', 7, 0]
['Senior', 6, 0]
['Javascript / Typescript', 6, 0]
['Php', 5, 0]
['JavaScript ', 5, 0]
['Elixir', 5, 0]
['ABAP', 5, 0]
['QA', 4, 0]
['AWS', 4, 0]
['c++', 3, 0]
['Ruby on Rails', 3, 0]
['React', 3, 0]
['Node.js', 3, 0]
['Golang', 3, 0]
['Embedded', 3, 0]
['Cloud', 3, 0]
['5"', 3, 0]
['.Net', 3, 0]
['"TypeScript', 3, 0]
['"Swift', 3, 0]
['"C', 3, 0]
['"Angular', 3, 0]
['yaml', 2, 0]
['kotlin', 2, 0]
['js', 2, 0]
['go', 2, 0]
['Sql ', 2, 0]
['Spark', 2, 0]
['PHP ', 2, 0]
['NodeJS', 2, 0]
['JavaScript/Typescript', 2, 0]
['JavaScript / TypeScript', 2, 0]
['Java/Kotlin', 2, 0]
['Java ', 2, 0]
['Frontend', 2, 0]
['Figma', 2, 0]
['C/C++', 2, 0]
['Bash', 2, 0]
['Angular', 2, 0]
['"Scala', 2, 0]
['"JS', 2, 0]
['"C++', 2, 0]
['"C#', 2, 0]
['С#', 1, 0]
['Офмф', 1, 0]
['typescript', 1, 0]
['swift', 1, 0]
['sql', 1, 0]
['spark', 1, 0]
['several', 1, 0]
['scala', 1, 0]
['ruby on rails', 1, 0]
['python ', 1, 0]
['pythin', 1, 0]
['nothing', 1, 0]
['none', 1, 0]
['n/a', 1, 0]
['k8s', 1, 0]
['julia', 1, 0]
['jenkins bash', 1, 0]
['java/scala/go/clouds/devops', 1, 0]
['golang', 1, 0]
['embedded', 1, 0]
['consumer analysis', 1, 0]
['c/c++', 1, 0]
['c#', 1, 0]
['android', 1, 0]
['Web developer', 1, 0]
['VHDL', 1, 0]
['UML', 1, 0]
['Typescript / Angular', 1, 0]
['Typescript ', 1, 0]
['TypeScript/Angular', 1, 0]
['Test Management ', 1, 0]
['Terraform ', 1, 0]
['Terraform', 1, 0]
['TS', 1, 0]
['T-SQL', 1, 0]
['Swift/Kotlin', 1, 0]
['Sql', 1, 0]
['Spring', 1, 0]
['Scala / Python', 1, 0]
['Salesforce ', 1, 0]
['SWIFT', 1, 0]
['SRE', 1, 0]
['SAP BW / ABAP', 1, 0]
['SAP ABAP', 1, 0]
['SAP / ABAP', 1, 0]
['SAP', 1, 0]
['React.js / TypeScript', 1, 0]
['React JS', 1, 0]
['React / JavaScript', 1, 0]
['React ', 1, 0]
['Qml', 1, 0]
['Qlik', 1, 0]
['Python/SQL', 1, 0]
['Python/NLP', 1, 0]
['Python / JavaScript (React)', 1, 0]
['Python + SQL', 1, 0]
['Python (Django)', 1, 0]
['Pyrhon', 1, 0]
['PowerShell', 1, 0]
['Power BI', 1, 0]
['Perl', 1, 0]
['Pegasystems platform ', 1, 0]
['PM tools', 1, 0]
['PL/SQL', 1, 0]
['PHP/MySQL', 1, 0]
['Oracle', 1, 0]
['Objective-C', 1, 0]
['NodsJs', 1, 0]
['Nodejs', 1, 0]
['NodeJS/TS', 1, 0]
['Node', 1, 0]
['Network Automation', 1, 0]
['Network', 1, 0]
['Ml/Python', 1, 0]
['Management', 1, 0]
['Magento', 1, 0]
['ML', 1, 0]
['Linux Kernel', 1, 0]
['Linux', 1, 0]
['Kubrrnetes', 1, 0]
['Kotlin/PHP', 1, 0]
['Kotlin ', 1, 0]
['Js', 1, 0]
['Jira', 1, 0]
['Javascript/Typescript', 1, 0]
['Javascript ', 1, 0]
['JavaScript/TypeScript', 1, 0]
['JavaScript/ES6', 1, 0]
['JavaScript / typescript', 1, 0]
['Java/Scala', 1, 0]
['Java/Groovy', 1, 0]
['Java/C++', 1, 0]
['Java Backend', 1, 0]
['Java / Scala', 1, 0]
['Java & Distributed Systems Stuff', 1, 0]
['JavScript', 1, 0]
['JAVA', 1, 0]
['Haskell', 1, 0]
['Hardware', 1, 0]
['Google Cloud Platform', 1, 0]
['Golang ', 1, 0]
['Go/Python', 1, 0]
['GCP', 1, 0]
['FBD', 1, 0]
['Erlang', 1, 0]
['Embedded C++', 1, 0]
['DevOps', 1, 0]
['DWH', 1, 0]
['DC Management', 1, 0]
['Cobol', 1, 0]
['Clojure', 1, 0]
['Charles', 1, 0]
['C-Level', 1, 0]
['C++/c', 1, 0]
['C++/C#', 1, 0]
['C#/.NET', 1, 0]
['C# .NET', 1, 0]
['Business Development Manager Operation ', 1, 0]
['Blockchain', 1, 0]
['Azure', 1, 0]
['Aws Hadoop Postgre Typescript', 1, 0]
['Autonomous Driving', 1, 0]
['Atlassian JIRA', 1, 0]
['Apotheker', 1, 0]
['Apache Spark', 1, 0]
['Android/Kotlin', 1, 0]
['Agile', 1, 0]
['AI', 1, 0]
['4', 1, 0]
['--', 1, 0]
['-', 1, 0]
['"python', 1, 0]
['"php', 1, 0]
['"networking', 1, 0]
['"VB', 1, 0]
['"Typescript', 1, 0]
['"Terraform', 1, 0]
['"Sql', 1, 0]
['"Spark', 1, 0]
['"Sketch', 1, 0]
['"SAS', 1, 0]
['"Qlik BI Tool', 1, 0]
['"Pascal', 1, 0]
['"PS', 1, 0]
['"NodeJS', 1, 0]
['"NLP', 1, 0]
['"Linux/UNIX', 1, 0]
['"Kubernetes', 1, 0]
['"Kuberenetes', 1, 0]
['"Kotlin', 1, 0]
['"Js', 1, 0]
['"Javascript', 1, 0]
['"JavaScript', 1, 0]
['"Grails', 1, 0]
['"Go', 1, 0]
['"Frontend: react', 1, 0]
['"Computer Networking', 1, 0]
['"BI', 1, 0]
['"Azure', 1, 0]
['"AWS', 1, 0]
['".net', 1, 0]
['".Net', 1, 0]
[' there are no ranges in the firm "', 1, 0]
[' but as a lab scientist)"', 1, 0]
```

From the output above it can be seen that the ranking suffers from different kinds of entries and needs some fine-tuning. Here an attempt to fine-tune the result:

```
fineTuning = True
prgrLang = []
with open("IT_Salary_Survey_EU_2020.csv") as f:
    Lines = f.readlines()
    for line in Lines[1:]:
        entry = line.split(',')[8] # 9th column in CSV
        if fineTuning:
            entry = entry.replace('"',' ').replace("'"," ").replace('/',' ')
            entry = entry.replace('on rails',' ')
            entry = str.lower(entry)
            entry = entry.split()
            if isinstance(entry, str): Entry  = [entry]
            else: Entry = entry            
            Entry = [ str.strip(entry) for entry in Entry if entry] # skip ''             
        if isinstance(Entry, str): Entry  = [Entry] 
        prgrLang.extend(Entry)
noOfEntries = len(Lines)-1
from collections import Counter
objCounter = Counter(prgrLang)
lstResults = sorted( [ [value, key] 
                for key, value in objCounter.items() ], reverse=True )
lstResPerc = [ [key, value, int(100*value/noOfEntries)] 
            for value, key in lstResults ] 
print( *lstResPerc, sep='\n' )
```

which changes the ranking to:

```
['python', 227, 18]
['java', 209, 16]
['javascript', 96, 7]
['php', 73, 5]
['c++', 50, 3]
['typescript', 45, 3]
['c#', 35, 2]
['scala', 30, 2]
['kotlin', 30, 2]
['swift', 29, 2]
['go', 28, 2]
['.net', 27, 2]
['ruby', 23, 1]
['sql', 22, 1]
['js', 18, 1]
['c', 17, 1]
['middle', 12, 0]
['android', 10, 0]
['r', 9, 0]
['ios', 9, 0]
['kubernetes', 8, 0]
['abap', 8, 0]
['react', 7, 0]
['angular', 7, 0]
['senior', 6, 0]
['aws', 6, 0]
['spark', 5, 0]
['nodejs', 5, 0]
['golang', 5, 0]
['embedded', 5, 0]
['elixir', 5, 0]
['sap', 4, 0]
['qa', 4, 0]
['cloud', 4, 0]
['terraform', 3, 0]
['rails', 3, 0]
['on', 3, 0]
['node.js', 3, 0]
['management', 3, 0]
['linux', 3, 0]
['bi', 3, 0]
['bash', 3, 0]
['5', 3, 0]
['yaml', 2, 0]
['ts', 2, 0]
['qlik', 2, 0]
['platform', 2, 0]
['nlp', 2, 0]
['networking', 2, 0]
['network', 2, 0]
['ml', 2, 0]
['jira', 2, 0]
['frontend', 2, 0]
['figma', 2, 0]
['devops', 2, 0]
['azure', 2, 0]
['a', 2, 0]
['с#', 1, 0]
['офмф', 1, 0]
['web', 1, 0]
['vhdl', 1, 0]
['vb', 1, 0]
['unix', 1, 0]
['uml', 1, 0]
['tools', 1, 0]
['tool', 1, 0]
['there', 1, 0]
['the', 1, 0]
['test', 1, 0]
['t-sql', 1, 0]
['systems', 1, 0]
['stuff', 1, 0]
['sre', 1, 0]
['spring', 1, 0]
['sketch', 1, 0]
['several', 1, 0]
['scientist)', 1, 0]
['sas', 1, 0]
['salesforce', 1, 0]
['react.js', 1, 0]
['ranges', 1, 0]
['qml', 1, 0]
['pythin', 1, 0]
['pyrhon', 1, 0]
['ps', 1, 0]
['powershell', 1, 0]
['power', 1, 0]
['postgre', 1, 0]
['pm', 1, 0]
['pl', 1, 0]
['perl', 1, 0]
['pegasystems', 1, 0]
['pascal', 1, 0]
['oracle', 1, 0]
['operation', 1, 0]
['objective-c', 1, 0]
['nothing', 1, 0]
['none', 1, 0]
['nodsjs', 1, 0]
['node', 1, 0]
['no', 1, 0]
['n', 1, 0]
['mysql', 1, 0]
['manager', 1, 0]
['magento', 1, 0]
['lab', 1, 0]
['kubrrnetes', 1, 0]
['kuberenetes', 1, 0]
['kernel', 1, 0]
['k8s', 1, 0]
['julia', 1, 0]
['jenkins', 1, 0]
['javscript', 1, 0]
['in', 1, 0]
['haskell', 1, 0]
['hardware', 1, 0]
['hadoop', 1, 0]
['groovy', 1, 0]
['grails', 1, 0]
['google', 1, 0]
['gcp', 1, 0]
['frontend:', 1, 0]
['firm', 1, 0]
['fbd', 1, 0]
['es6', 1, 0]
['erlang', 1, 0]
['dwh', 1, 0]
['driving', 1, 0]
['distributed', 1, 0]
['development', 1, 0]
['developer', 1, 0]
['dc', 1, 0]
['consumer', 1, 0]
['computer', 1, 0]
['cobol', 1, 0]
['clouds', 1, 0]
['clojure', 1, 0]
['charles', 1, 0]
['c-level', 1, 0]
['bw', 1, 0]
['but', 1, 0]
['business', 1, 0]
['blockchain', 1, 0]
['backend', 1, 0]
['autonomous', 1, 0]
['automation', 1, 0]
['atlassian', 1, 0]
['as', 1, 0]
['are', 1, 0]
['apotheker', 1, 0]
['apache', 1, 0]
['analysis', 1, 0]
['ai', 1, 0]
['agile', 1, 0]
['4', 1, 0]
['--', 1, 0]
['-', 1, 0]
['+', 1, 0]
['(react)', 1, 0]
['(django)', 1, 0]
['&', 1, 0]
```